# What is the difference in contacts versus raw-contacts?

Tags: android, contacts, contactscontract, rawcontacts

I have a "dump" utility that I am using to study the ContactsContract since I don't quite get it in the documentation.  When I dump the contacts it counts 263 records in the table, however, the contacts application on my device lists that I have 244 ("Displaying 244 contacts.")

Can someone explain the discrepancy?

My Sprint LG's Contacts App has display options for each of the accounts that I sync and I have gone in and checked all of them, so there shouldn't be any filtering.

The main URI that I am using in the utility is:

```
    Uri uriRawContacts = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String [] {
            ContactsContract.RawContactsEntity._ID,
            ContactsContract.RawContactsEntity.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.RawContactsEntity.DELETED,
            ContactsContract.RawContactsEntity.AGGREGATION_MODE,
    };
    Cursor cursorRaw = cr.query(uriRawContacts, projection, null, null, null);
    DumpCursor.dumpAnyCursor(getApplicationContext(), "RawContacts", cr, cursorRaw, ",");
```

Followed by (for each _ID in the above query):

```
                long rawContactId = Long.parseLong(anyCursor.getString(anyCursor.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.CONTACT_ID)));

                Uri rawContactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, rawContactId);
                 Uri entityUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(rawContactUri, Entity.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

                 Log.d(TAG, "rawContactUri: " + rawContactUri.toString());
                 Log.d(TAG, "entityUri: " + entityUri.toString());

                 Cursor c = cr.query(entityUri, new String[] { RawContacts.SOURCE_ID, Entity.DATA_ID, Entity.MIMETYPE, Entity.DATA1 }, null, null, null);
```

I then loop through the first query, display all the columns in my projection, then, using the _ID field in the first query's loop, I issue the second query and dump all of its columns.

**Bullets from the answer transposed here for convenience:**
*Refer to the reference for more detailed explanation.  More specifically, you are encouraged to read about the aggregation rules.*
Ref: [Click here for the original cited text that follows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151885/android-new-data-record-is-added-to-the-wrong-contact/5158059#5158059)

> - The Contacts database is divided into    3 tables contacts, raw
>     contacts, and    data.
> - Each table contains column (_ID)    which is an auto incremented primary
>     key.
> - The data table contains all the contact    info like phone number, mail id,
>     address etc.
> - The raw contacts points to the actual    contact created. Hence we
>     use the raw    contacts while adding a
>     contact.
> - The user cannot add any data in the    contacts table. The data in this
>     table is populated internally due to
>     aggregation of contacts.
>
> The reason your logic worked for some
>   of the contacts is: _ID for contacts,
>   raw contacts remains same until there
>   is any contact aggregation taking
>   place. Lets say you add two contacts
>   with same name abc. Here the _ID for
>   raw contacts increments twice while
>   _ID for contacts increments only once as these two contacts gets merged due
>   to the aggregation of contacts

Comment: The last approved Edit was incorrect.  If you read the original, you will see the missing punctuation and the emphasis on the 3 tables.  Then s/he makes a reference to that as "The data table, 'contacts' contains all the ..."  You have modified the original author's correct statements.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This difference is due to `RawContacts` getting merged to `Contacts` due to the aggregation rule.

You add contact to `RawContacts` while the list displays Contacts. Hence the count difference.

Please find some description between `Contacts`, `RawContacts` and `Data` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151885/android-new-data-record-is-added-to-the-wrong-contact/5158059#5158059).
Even though the question is a different one you might be able to get the difference between `Contacts` and `RawContacts`.

Comment: Super answer and +1.  I think the info is important enough that I am going to ref and transpose the six bullets from that answer into this Q&A.

Answer (score 5):

The three tables are commonly referred to by the names of their contract classes. The classes define constants for content URIs, column names, and column values used by the tables:

`ContactsContract.Contacts` table :- 
Rows representing different people, based on aggregations of raw contact rows.

`ContactsContract.RawContacts` table :-
Rows containing a summary of a person's data, specific to a user account and type.

`ContactsContract.Data` table :-
Rows containing the details for raw contact, such as email addresses or phone numbers.

for more info [click](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html)

Comment: suppose I want to get the id that apps use to open chat intents, such as viber, how do I do that? For example, if Viber has a contact X, it has some ID for it Y, which is used to open an intent of chat with this contact , using: intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/"+id)); intent.setPackage("com.viber.voip");

Comment: I can't find the needed ID for this. Can you please help? I've made a post about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35972329/878126