# Using WhatsApp URI to open Caller

Tags: android, iphone, xamarin, whatsapp

Using the What's API URI I can integrate it into my iPhone and Android app nicely to send a text.

**For example: whatsapp://send?text=xamarin**

I have not seen in the WhatsApp docs how to open the **caller** function.

Basically I wish to open the call dialer in the WhatsApp from my app just like I can do so to send a Text.

Comment: Not exposed via their API (iOS: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013) (Android https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012/)

Comment: I don't know the solution for IOS, but if you can somehow invoke opening of a URL there, this might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54108061/878126 . Search for the part of "prepareWhatsAppMessageIntent" . Example URL: `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=normalizedPhoneNumber&text=abc` or: `https://wa.me/normalizedPhoneNumber&text=abc`

Answer (score 0):

I found a way-ish

From iPhone or Android cause the default browser to open this link, it will send you to WhatsApp for that number (`if you have that contact`). You'll have to tap the `Phone icon` as the default is to open the `Chat`.

`https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+1THE-NUMBER-HERE-WITH-COUNTRY-CODE`

Comment: Is there something similar for Duo?