# Send msg to particular WhatsApp contact saved without country code

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp, start-activity

This following line sends a message to a particular Whats App contact

```
"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + phone + "&text=" + URLEncoder.encode(msg, "UTF-8");
```

Reference : [How can I send message to specific contact through WhatsApp from my android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36344892/how-can-i-send-message-to-specific-contact-through-whatsapp-from-my-android-app/43994093#43994093)

But the above URL needs phone number with country code. I need to send message to phone number which are not saved with country codes. How to do that any idea?

Comment: So, to what country will you send it to?

Comment: It can be from any country to any country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean you definitely need to know the country code somehow. you might be able to get it from the phone (read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402253/getting-telephone-us-local-area-code-with-android) for instance) in case it is absent.
then once you have it you simply write

```
phone="+"+foundCountryCode+phone;
```

but before you do that you need to check if the phone nr. doesnt already have a country code as some of the users contacts might be from other countries (we live in a globalized world) so simply check if the phone String begins with "+" or "00" and only perform the adjustment above in case it does not.

I did the following

```
public static String depuratePhone(String rawPhone){
    String phone=rawPhone.replace(" ","").replace("+","00").replace("-","");
    String depPhone=null;
    if (phone.length()>2){
        if (phone.substring(0,2).contentEquals("00")){
            depPhone=phone;
        }else{
            depPhone="00"+your_current_country_code+phone;
        }
    }
    return depPhone;

}
```

in order to get your own phones country code amazingly it seems you always have to create your own [database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12848920/10637400) of country codes as all you can get from the phone are 2 letter string codes for your country. I am also amazed that there is not a way to get this directly from the phone. Amazing, I wonder what the justification for this is.

the freaking TelephonyManager even lets you get your own phone number if you grant it a ton of permissions but not a simple country code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We live in a globalised World and that is my exact problem. I can get the device country code but how do I know the country code of a particular phone number if it is saved in phonebook without country code? I might be in living in USA but I can save a phone number of India without +91. The phone string(10 digits) can be saved and often people save without '+' or '00'

Comment: I think that would rarely happen as it would be impossible to call the person from india while im in the us. i know this first hand actually as i bought my phone in a different country and was too lazy to change the locale

Comment: Ill add some code from an app I made for my own country, I also had to take account of the fact that plenty of people here have whatsapp accounts from the US or Spain

Comment: btw there is a dependency you can install to avoid having to create your own DB look at this answer for reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/48873912/10637400 the dependency is this one https://github.com/MichaelRocks/libphonenumber-android