# Android Contacts._ID != Data.CONTACT_ID

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm running a query against `CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI`  and I'm getting all the results that have a NOT NULL phone id.

pretty much the code is :

```
    String[] projection2 = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,          
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,                              
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,             
        };
    String where2 = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + " != ''" ;


    Cursor phoneCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            projection2, where2, null, null);
```

and then I iterate through each cursor result and getting the columns I want.
The code is :

```
           if (phoneCursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                String contacts_id = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String phone_id = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
                    Log.i("phonecursor", "contacts_id= "  + contacts_id + " phone_id " + phone_id 
                            +  "  contacts_name= "  + contacts_name + " phone_name= " + phone_name
                            + " Phone= " + phone  );

            }
            phoneCursor.close();
        }
```

What I dont get is why Phone.CONTACT_ID is different from the corresponding Contacts._ID from the same row...

Shouldn't both be the same? There are a lot of examples that use those exact columns to run queries. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12562234/423980) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151885/android-new-data-record-is-added-to-the-wrong-contact/5158059#5158059) if you check the Key pointers.

Answer (score 28):

`ContactsContract.Contacts._ID` returns unique ID for a row

[This is very good example](https://androidexample.com/get-contact-emails-content-provider)

> [image]

<sup>[Image](https://androidexample.com/upload/content/Content_provider_get_email_workflow.png) from [Get Contact Emails By Content Provider - Android Example](https://androidexample.com/get-contact-emails-content-provider)</sup>

Answer (score 6):

`ContactsContract.Contacts._ID` returns unique ID for a row.

Now the output will vary based on which `cursor` you are querying `ContactsContract.Contacts._ID`.

If you query `ContactsContract.Contacts._ID` from `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` , you will get `ContactsContract.Contacts._ID` and `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID` same.

But if you query `ContactsContract.Contacts._ID` from `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI` you will get `ContactsContract.Contacts._ID` and `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID` different as on each phone entry `ContactsContract.Contacts._ID` is incremented.

So if you want same _ID and Phone._ID then query from `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` instead of `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI`